# Ember and Rails polymorphic relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have been looking up different solutions for this problem but I can't seem to find any sort of conclusion as how best to deal with polymorphic relationships between Rails and Ember. In my case I have a polymorphic table called "todos" and one of the relationships to that table is called "patient". I get the todo records but they don't know what patient they are associated with. Any help into this would be greatly appreciated.

RAILS MODELS:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todoable, polymorphic: true
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos, as: :todoable
end
```

RAILS SERIALIZERS:

```
class TodoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :content, :todoable_id, :todoable_type
end

class PatientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email
  has_many :todos
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

EMBER DATA MODELS:

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend
  todoable_id: DS.attr 'number'
  todoable_type: DS.attr 'string'
  content: DS.attr 'string'
  patient: DS.belongsTo 'patient'

App.Patient = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr 'string'
  lastName: DS.attr 'string'
  email: DS.attr 'string'
  todos: DS.hasMany 'todo', polymorphic: true, async: true
```

Comment: Why do you have both `belongs_to :todoable` and `belongs_to :patient`?

Comment: @SergioA. Good catch. That shouldn't be there. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually a normal many-to-one relationship (ie. many Todos can belong to one Patient) and not a polymorphic relationship. If you said, "*Todos can belong to a Patient or a Doctor or a Dog*", then polymorphism might be the answer.

So, you can simply do:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end
```

And in Ember:

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend
  patient: DS.belongsTo 'patient'

App.Patient = DS.Model.extend
  todos: DS.hasMany 'todo', async: true
```